# Is there a Ruby method that's equivalent to drop_while for hashes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I know for arrays I can do the following to drop the first red and keep the second. Is there an equivalent for hashes?

```
colors = ["red", "yellow", "orange", "red", "green", "majenta"]
test = colors.drop_while {|x| x.length < 4}
p test
```

The best I could come up with from past questions is the following, but it doesn't quite work.

```
colors = {
      first: "red",
      second: "yellow",
      third: "green",
      fourth: "red"
}
colors.delete_if{|k,v| v.length < 4 ? true : break }
```

Comment: Even though newer Ruby hashes are 'soft/insertion ordered', this really shouldn't be used outside of informational/diagnostic purposes. As such they do not expose any operations that establish or rely on key ordering (except, arguably, for iteration). One *could* hash -> key-value array -> x_while -> hash, but .. it might also indicate that a hash isn't the appropriate structure for the desired task.

Comment: @user2864740, I beg to differ. I've made good use of Ruby's maintenance of key-insertion ordering, my answer [here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/40776/number-to-words-problem#21293260) being an example.

Comment: What's wrong with just using `drop_while`?

Answer (score 1):

```
colors.drop_while { |_, v| v.length < 4 }
```

Comment: I didn't know there was an `Enumerable#drop_while`, so I was working on creating `Hash#drop_while`. Needless to say, I've abandoned that effort. :-).

Comment: @CarySwoveland yours always might be more efficient, fancy and new-wheel-like :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if you perused the Enumerable docs, you would notice that the Enumerable module contains a drop_while iterator. Since both the classes Array and Hash include the Enumerable module, you can use any of the Enumerable instance methods on them.

```
Hash.new.is_a?(Enumerable)
 => true 
Array.new.is_a?(Enumerable)
 => true
```

drop_while instance method of Enumerable seems straightforward but there is an important point to note about it. It will drop elements that return false or nil UNTIL it returns a truthy value. And thereafter, even if the elements return false or nil, they will be included in the output. As shown:

```
[1,2,4,6,1,8].drop_while {|i| i.odd? }  
=> [2, 4, 6, 1, 8]
```

Given the aforementioned knowledge, yes you can do this:

```
colors = {:first=>"red", :second=>"yellow", :third=>"green", :fourth=>"red"}
colors.drop_while {|_,v| v == "red" }.to_h
 => {:second=>"yellow", :third=>"green", :fourth=>"red"}
```

Or you could also do this (but will lose the hash keys):

```
colors.values.drop_while {|color| color == "red"}
 => ["yellow", "green", "red"]
```

Ultimately, since both Hash and Array include the Enumerable module, you can use this instance method on either.